# How do I convert nested enums containing a struct from Swift to Java?

Tags: java, swift, struct, enums

I am trying to convert the following **Swift 4.1.2** code to **Java 1.5** or above.  I have nested enums which contain various structs.

```
import UIKit

enum CreateOrder
{
  enum FormatUseByDate
  {
    struct Request
    {
      var date: Date
    }
    struct Response
    {
      var date: Date
    }
    struct ViewModel
    {
      var date: String
    }
  }
}
```

Java does not support the `struct` keyword.  However, a `struct` equivalent to one of the structs above could be:

```
class Request
{
  public Date date;
}
```

I have made several attempts at creating the nested enums and referencing the struct equivalent. Such as:

```
import java.util.Date;

interface Usecase {
}

class Response implements Usecase {
    public Date date;
}

class Request implements Usecase {
    public Date date;
}

class ViewModel implements Usecase {
    String date;
}


public class EnumDemo {

    enum CreateOrder {

        FORMATUSEBYDATE;

        enum FormatUseByDate {

            REQUEST(new Request()), RESPONSE(new Response()), VIEWMODEL(new ViewModel());

            Usecase usecase;

            FormatUseByDate(Request req) {
                this.usecase = req;
            }

            FormatUseByDate(Response res) {
                this.usecase = res;
            }

            FormatUseByDate(ViewModel vm) {
                this.usecase = vm;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CreateOrder.FormatUseByDate.REQUEST); // Attempt at referencing the REQUEST struct equivalent
    }

}
```

However, I'm not sure how to reference the `class` which is to be used as `struct` equivalent from an enum and whether they can be defined within the body of the enum.

Comment: Um, this might be one of those cases where you revisit your actual use case instead of trying to convert apples to apples. What are you even trying to do? Why does 'FormatUseByDate' need to be nested inside of CreateOrder?

Comment: In Swift, no-case enums are often used as namespace. You should not convert them into Java `enum`. And I do not understand why you need `UseCase` thing.

Comment: I am trying to create a data structure that can be conveniently referenced as a data model throughout the code.  This is an attempt at implementing Clean Architecture.  FormatUseByDate is just an example. So the data structure is intended to be used in this manner _UseCase.Something.Request_, _UseCase.Something.Response_ or _UseCase.Something.ViewModel_.  So instead of FormatUseByDate it could be e.g. EditOrder or UpdateOrder etc. 

Other examples could be e.g. CreateOrder.EditOrder.Request, CreateOrder.UpdateOrder.Response or ShowOrder.GetOrder.ViewModel.

Comment: That does not mean you need Java `enum`. But if you have your own way. Go with your way without posting questions.

Comment: As OOPer mentioned, no-case enums = namespace. The Java concept of namespace is **package**. So, `package CreateOrder.FormatUseByDate; public class Request { public Date date; }`

Comment: I see what you mean.  Thanks OOPer and Andreas for clarifying no-case enum usage in Swift (I'm a Swift newbie) and for pointing out that the Java equivalence is using **package**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could write something like this if I really needed something like `CreateOrder.UpdateOrder.Response`, but you should know something *Clean* in Swift may not be clean in Java.

```
import java.util.Date;

public final class CreateOrder {
    private CreateOrder() {}

    public final class FormatUseByDate {
        private FormatUseByDate() {}

        public class Response {
            public Date date;

            @Override
            public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                Object cloned = super.clone();
                //...
                return cloned;
            }
        }

        public class Request {
            public Date date;

            @Override
            public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                Object cloned = super.clone();
                //...
                return cloned;
            }
        }

        public class ViewModel {
            String date;

            @Override
            public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                Object cloned = super.clone();
                //...
                return cloned;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to call `clone()` for every assignment (including passing an argument to methods) to simulate the value semantics of Swift `struct`.

Comment: Thanks OOPer for demonstrating how it could be done. I will try using Java packages.